# android setonclicklistener override errors

Tags: java, android

All my errors are mostly at buttonEntry, buttonMail and buttonSettings declarations, at setonclicklistener. Errors are:

- Error:(26, 63) error: cannot find symbol class AddEntry
- Error:(23, 65) error:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method onClick(View) in OnClickListener
- Error:(29, 22) error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
- Error:(24, 11) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Can anyone help solving this problems? I'm still a beginner, and I have no ideea why it throws so many errors. Also, if I try to put on my main_menu.xml android:onClick="MethodName", my application gets stop responding, when I open it on emulator, without any error on building.

```
    Button buttonEntry;
    Button buttonMail;
    Button buttonSettings;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonEntry = (Button)findViewById(R.id.action_add_entry);
      buttonEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void OnClick(View v) {
                 Intent entry = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddEntry.class);
                 startActivity(entry);
              setContentView(R.layout.newentry);
              return true;
          }
      });
        buttonMail = (Button)findViewById(R.id.action_add_email);
        buttonMail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnClick(View v) {
                   Intent mail = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddMail.class);
                   startActivity(mail);
                setContentView(R.layout.newmail);
                return true;
            }
        });
        buttonSettings = (Button)findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
        buttonSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnClick(View v) {
                   Intent settings = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AppSettings.class);
                    startActivity(settings);
                setContentView(R.layout.settings);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Activity_Manifest, here is the 3 activity I added. Got their names in red.

```
<activity android:name=".AddEntry"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddMail"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AppSettings"></activity>
```

Comment: can you post the activity_main.xml, also why are you calling setContentView right after starting a new Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Button buttonEntry;
Button buttonMail;
Button buttonSettings;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonEntry = (Button)findViewById(R.id.action_add_entry);
  buttonEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent entry = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddEntry.class);
             startActivity(entry);
          setContentView(R.layout.newentry);
      }
  });
    buttonMail = (Button)findViewById(R.id.action_add_email);
    buttonMail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent mail = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddMail.class);
               startActivity(mail);
            setContentView(R.layout.newmail);

        }
    });
    buttonSettings = (Button)findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
    buttonSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent settings = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AppSettings.class);
                startActivity(settings);
            setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        }
    });
}
```

Error:(26, 63) error: cannot find symbol class AddEntry
If AddEntry is in another .java, you need to import on top of your file, like this:

```
import your.package.name.AddEntry;
```

Comment: Solved most of the problems, thanks, but there is only 1 error left, the one with symbols. I tried to use import package.name.AddEntry;, but I still got the same error. I updated my main post with activities I added in activity main, got their names in red, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Please check content of your activity layout file `activity_main.xml`.
It need to have `Button` elements with `id` attribute set to according value.

For example in your case for next line of code to work properly

```
 buttonEntry = (Button)findViewById(R.id.action_add_entry);
```

you need to add to `activity_main.xml` Button element that will look something like this

```
...
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:id="@+id/action_add_entry" />
...
```

Take note on `android:id` attribute.

Comment: That isnt he's problem. Missing ID will throw a NullException, he didnt get it yet.